# adding a new column to csv and populate the values alternatives

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to write a batch file in windows which copies / appends a new column at the starting of CSV file . and then populates with values 0 and 1 alternately

For Example:

```
F1,F2,F3
1,2,3
1,2,3
2,3,4
3,4,5
```

Now I wish to add a new column at first and add values to them
ex

```
F0,F1,F2,F3
0,1,2,3
1,1,2,3
0,2,3,4
1,3,4,5
```

Just append 0 for all even row numbers and 1 for all odd rows

Below is the code that I have written, but that just adds 0 to all rows, but I want 0 and 1 alternately

```
@echo off > newfile.csv & setLocal enableDELAYedeXpansion
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (J_CAFE27032018_090325.csv) do (
>> newfile.csv echo a,%%a
)
```

A c equivalent would be having a for loop for all even and odd columns

```
for(i=0;i<n;i+2)
 {
   add 0
 }
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
 {
   add 0
 }
```

Would you please help me with the batch file equivalent to traverse each odd and even rows.

Comment: You need a counter a modulus division and delayed expansion. Look this up here in SO or in ss64.com

Answer (score 2):

This method is the same as Aacini's however it prepends the header line with `#,`, *(can be modified)*.

```bat
@Echo Off & SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "i=" & (For /F "UseBackQ Delims=" %%A In ("J_CAFE27032018_090325.csv") Do (
    If Defined i (Echo !i!,%%A) Else Set "i=1" & Echo #,%%A
    Set /A "i=(i+1)%%2"))>newfile.csv & Exit /B
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it the following way -- given that no line of the input CSV file (`data.csv`) exceeds an overall length of 1021 characters/bytes:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_FILE=%~1" & rem // (CSV file to process; use first argument)
set "_SEP=,"    & rem // (separator character)
set "_HEAD=F0"  & rem // (header text for new column)
set /A "_MOD=2" & rem // (divisor for modulo operation)
set /A "_OFF=0" & rem // (offset for modulo operation)

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem // Determine number of lines contained in CSV file:
for /F %%C in ('^< "!_FILE!" find /C /V ""') do set /A "COUNT=%%C"
rem // Read from CSV file:
< "!_FILE!" (
    rem // Check whether header text is defined:
    if defined _HEAD (
        rem // Header text defined, so read current header:
        set "LINE=" & set /P LINE=""
        rem // Prepend header text for new column to current line:
        echo(!_HEAD!!_SEP!!LINE!
        rem // Decrement number of lines:
        set /A "COUNT-=1"
    )
    rem // Process remaining lines in a loop:
    for /L %%I in (1,1,!COUNT!) do (
        rem // Read current line:
        set "LINE=" & set /P LINE=""
        rem // Perform modulo operation:
        set /A "NUM=(%%I+_OFF-1)%%!_MOD!"
        rem // Prepend remainder of division to current line:
        echo(!NUM!!_SEP!!LINE!
    )
)
endlocal

endlocal
exit /B
```

This approach uses [input redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) to read from the input CSV file.

To write the output to another CSV file, say `data-mod.csv`, rather than to the console, use the following command line, assuming the script is called `prepend-modulo.bat` and the input CSV file is named `data.csv`, and both reside in the current directory:

```cmd
prepend-modulo.bat "data.csv" > "data_mod.csv"
```

Comment: how to copy output directly to destination file  from code

Comment: What is rem here ? isee that the first column is -1 here and cant trace why is it happening.Thanks again

Comment: `rem` is a remark. You can overwrite your original file by `move /Y "data_mod.csv" "data.csv"` after the script executed. Are you talking about the line `set /A "COUNT-=1"`? this subtracts `1` from the number of remaining rows (it's `-=`, not `=-`)...

Comment: i meant the output has -1 as the first column value to newly added field  follwed by 0's and 1's

Comment: Strange, I did not get `-1`... did you copy the script correctly? what parameters and constants did you specify?

Comment: I ran this code exactly and first rows first column is -1

Comment: Oops, sorry, there was a small typo in the `for /L` loop -- I corrected it in my answer...

Answer (score 1):

This is one of several ways to do it:

```
@echo off & setLocal enableDELAYedeXpansion
set "i=0"
(for /f "delims=" %%a in (J_CAFE27032018_090325.csv) do (
   echo !i!,%%a
   set /A "i=(i+1)%%2"
)) > newfile.csv
```

However your original logic dos not correctly process the header (first) line...

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q50041056.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"
SET "firstline=Y"
SET "zerostart=Y"
(
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 IF DEFINED firstline (
  ECHO F0,%%a
  SET "firstline="
 ) ELSE (
  IF DEFINED zerostart (
   ECHO 0,%%a
   SET "zerostart="
  ) ELSE (
   ECHO 1,%%a
   SET "zerostart=Y"
  )
 )
)
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q50041056.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Produces the file defined as %outfile%

The `usebackq` option is only required because I chose to add quotes around the source filename.

This solution uses the fact that `if defined` interprets the *current* status of the variablename, so the variable in question is simply toggled between a value and *nothing*.